Longitudinal and Transverse phonons
I was looking at this demonstration of acoustic and optical phonons and it seems to me that the animation has 'transverse' and 'longitudinal' upside down.
Am I correct? For instance the picture below has atoms moving back and forth but the transverse box is checked.


I agree: if you check the transverse button (so that it has a green checkmark), you are confusingly turning the transverse waves off.

You are right! Looking at the animation when the the "transverse" button is checked, both the upper and the lower wave (running in horizontal direction) are actually longitudinal optical and acoustic waves (phonons). When the "transverse" button is not checked, you actually see transverse acoustic and optical waves (phonons).
